# What can be the algorithm to find the max number that appear the most in an array?

Tags: java, algorithm

I'm trying to find out an algorithm that returns the number that has more occurrences in an `array` that contains number from 0 to 9 and that has a complexity of `n`.
I though to using an `HashMap` but it would require `n^2`
If anyone can write the code down,i'd prefer in Java but pseudocode is the same

Comment: SO isn't here to write your code, but to answer questions you have on _stuff  you wrote._ Please try writing something yourself and ask for assistance then.

Comment: Also, why n^2? You only have to go through the array once, and then through the HashMap values once.

Comment: A hash map is overkill, the key values are contiguous and in a small range.

Comment: [Why is “Can someone help me?” not an actual question?](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/284236)

Answer (score 4):

Use ten counters (one per digit), scan the array and increment the counters corresponding to the digits. (You are actually computing the histogram of the digit frequencies.)

Report the digit with the largest counter.